# Python: How to make a classes `__call__` method accept both NumPy arrays and single values?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, class

For a regular function like this

```
def f(t):
    return t*t
```

I can pass *both* a value or a NumPy array without issue. E.g. this works:

```
T = 1
print(f(T))

times = np.mgrid[0 : T : 100j]
values = f(times)
```

Now I made a class with a `__call__` function

```
class rnd_elemental_integrand:
    
    def __init__(self, n_sections, T):
        
        self.n_sections = n_sections
        self.T = T
        self.generate()
        
    def generate(self):
        self.values = norm.rvs(size = (self.n_sections + 1,), scale = 1)

    def __call__(self, t):
        ind = int(t * (self.n_sections/self.T))
        return self.values[ind]
```

But for this class method I can **not** pass a NumPy array. E.g. this

```
T = 5
elem_int_sections = 10

rnd_elem = rnd_elemental_integrand(elem_int_sections, T)

print(rnd_elem(T))
times = np.mgrid[0 : T : 100j]
values = rnd_elem(times)
```

produces the output

```
0.43978851468955377
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/gnthr/Desktop/Programming/Python/StochAna/stochana.py", line 138, in <module>
    values = rnd_elem(times)
  File "/Users/gnthr/Desktop/Programming/Python/StochAna/stochana.py", line 117, in __call__
    ind = int(t * (self.n_sections/self.T))
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

From other posts I know that vectorising a `__call__` method via some `np.` function would work, but e.g. the function `f` above is also not vectorised and works fine with both types of inputs. Can this class `__call__` method be made to accept both argument types (floats & array's of floats)?

Comment: This depends purely on the code inside the `__call__` method, not the fact that that code is inside a `__call__` method. `__call__` is irrelevant.

Comment: If you had tried to call `int` on an array outside of a `__call__` method, you would have had the exact same issue.

Comment: Just make a judgment: `prod = t * (self.n_sections/self.T)`, `ind = prod.astype(int) if isinstance(prod, np.ndarray) else int(prod)`, or use the int type in numpy: `ind = np.int_(prod)`

Comment: Thank you both!
This helped my understanding and `ind = np.int_(prod)` solved the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Fix:** without the type checking.

Since `np.array` can accept inputs of both `np.array`  and  scalar we can create a new `np.array` of type int

```
ind = np.array(t * (self.n_sections/self.T), dtype=int)
```

Testcase:

```
from scipy.stats import norm
T = 5
elem_int_sections = 10

rnd_elem = rnd_elemental_integrand(elem_int_sections, T)

print(rnd_elem(T))
times = np.mgrid[0 : T : 100j]
print (rnd_elem(times))
```

output:

```
-0.7828585207846585
[-1.00037782 -1.00037782 -1.00037782 -1.00037782 -1.00037782 -1.00037782
 -1.00037782 -1.00037782 -1.00037782 -1.00037782  1.35744571  1.35744571
  1.35744571  1.35744571  1.35744571  1.35744571  1.35744571  1.35744571
  1.35744571  1.35744571  0.65442428  0.65442428  0.65442428  0.65442428
  0.65442428  0.65442428  0.65442428  0.65442428  0.65442428  0.65442428
  0.76685108  0.76685108  0.76685108  0.76685108  0.76685108  0.76685108
  0.76685108  0.76685108  0.76685108  0.76685108  0.48888641  0.48888641
  0.48888641  0.48888641  0.48888641  0.48888641  0.48888641  0.48888641
  0.48888641  0.48888641  0.62681856  0.62681856  0.62681856  0.62681856
  0.62681856  0.62681856  0.62681856  0.62681856  0.62681856  0.62681856
  1.05695641  1.05695641  1.05695641  1.05695641  1.05695641  1.05695641
  1.05695641  1.05695641  1.05695641  1.05695641 -0.0634099  -0.0634099
 -0.0634099  -0.0634099  -0.0634099  -0.0634099  -0.0634099  -0.0634099
 -0.0634099  -0.0634099  -0.00167191 -0.00167191 -0.00167191 -0.00167191
 -0.00167191 -0.00167191 -0.00167191 -0.00167191 -0.00167191 -0.00167191
  1.16756173  1.16756173  1.16756173  1.16756173  1.16756173  1.16756173
  1.16756173  1.16756173  1.16756173 -0.78285852]
```